# Did i successfully pass the certification?

Tags: certification

I just completed the certification exam (Magento developer plus) and no paper was given to me.
I am not sure if I have successfully passed the exam.

At the end of the test, there was a message “Congratulations! You have passed the Magento Developer plus certification”.
Please, what does it mean ? Success or not ? (the term “pass” is ambiguous in French).

Comment: Yes,you have passed the exam,,Congrats you are now magento certified developer plus..:-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First of all congrats to you.**

You must got **a  print result from  your exam center**

If your  Exam center `is magento authorize`,then in a week, you will get mail from `magento.com`. with link  of magento clarification https://www.magentocommerce.com/certification/directory

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll try to contact the exam center to get this print.
(Btw, it looks like i'm not in the right section, sorry for that)